# How to fix Puppeteer's The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is xyz error?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

Chrome OS version : Google Chrome 60.0.3112.113

OS version : OS : CentOs7 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64

The following is my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core'); 
const fs = require('fs'); 

let browser = null;


const chromeOptions = {
    executablePath:' /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable', 
    headless:true, 
    ignoreDefaultArgs:["--enable-automation"], 
    args: ['--start-fullscreen',"--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"], 
    slowMo:5,
    timeout:30000,
    defaultViewport: null
};


async function getBrowser(){        
    if(null == browser){
        browser  = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
    }
    return browser;
}

async function closeBrowser(){
    if(browser) {
        await browser.close(); 
    }
}


(async function main() {
    
        
 await getBrowser();
 await browser.newPage();                
            
        
})();
```

I got the following error.

> (node:24642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Timed out
> after 3000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome
> revision guaranteed to work is r594312
> at Timeout.onTimeout (/opt/xxx/node-v14.16.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:350:14)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

Is there any way to fix this error ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: The given revision number points to "Chromium 71.0.3563.0" - have you tried running that? The version of Chrome you are using is four years old, so why not update it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Updating the chrome to latest version worked.